# jquery passing result of an ajax call into an inner ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use jquery to change a table's content based on two ajax calls. One of these ajax calls is inside the outer one. I've tried to simplify my code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../actions.php",
    data: { username: username, catId: $('#prodCat').val(), brandId: $('#prodBrand').val(),
            typeId: $('#prodType').val(), NameId: $('#prodName').val()},
    success: function(data){
        $('#prodList').empty();
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        var tableRows='';
        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var qtyArray = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../actions.php",
                data: { action : 'get_product_carton_single', mainStockId: <?php echo "'".$stockId."'" ?>, productId: result[i]['id']},
                success: function(databack){
                    qtyArray = databack;
                    console.log(qtyArray);
                    tableRows += '<tr>';
                    tableRows += '<td>' + result[i]['id'] + '</td>';
                    tableRows += '<td>' + (i+1) + '</td>';
                    tableRows += '<td>' + result[i]['productname'] + '</td>';                    
                    tableRows += '<td>' + qtyArray['carton'] + '</td>';
                    tableRows += '<td>' + qtyArray['single'] + '</td>';
                    tableRows += '<td class="quantityField"><input class="quantityInput" type="text" name="'+result[i]['id']+'" value="0" data-product-id="'+result[i]['id']+'" data-max-value="'+result[i]['quantity']+'"></td>';
                    tableRows += '</tr>';
                }
            });
        }
        $('#prodList').append(tableRows);
    }
});
```

But I get the following error :

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

but when I put this part :

tableRows += '';

```
            tableRows += '<td>' + result[i]['id'] + '</td>';
            tableRows += '<td>' + (i+1) + '</td>';
            tableRows += '<td>' + result[i]['productname'] + '</td>';                    
            tableRows += '<td>' + qtyArray['carton'] + '</td>';
            tableRows += '<td>' + qtyArray['single'] + '</td>';
            tableRows += '<td class="quantityField"><input class="quantityInput" type="text" name="'+result[i]['id']+'" value="0" data-product-id="'+result[i]['id']+'" data-max-value="'+result[i]['quantity']+'"></td>';
            tableRows += '</tr>';
```

Outside of the inner ajax call, the `result` variable is accessible but the `qtyArray` is not. which I guess is because it is not initiated yet.

How can I get both  `result` and `qtyArray` to update my table.

**EDIT:**

Here is a sample of results coming from first ajax call :
https://jsfiddle.net/8zdey0cv/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript/jQuery Variable Scope Issue with Nested .ajax() calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375399/javascript-jquery-variable-scope-issue-with-nested-ajax-calls)

Comment: Problem is that the value of i continues to increase, eventually being greater than the limit, at which point your results[i] blows out. You need to create a closure. See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375399/javascript-jquery-variable-scope-issue-with-nested-ajax-calls

Comment: @VanquishedWombat yeah your right but why does it continue to increase?  I have a condition in for loop i <result.length ?

Comment: What you think happens is that when you call the ajax functions the value of var i is fixed within the function. This is not the case - most likely because the success functions don't actually run until the client-server-client message chain is completed.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat thanks. but sorry it is not still clear for me. could you please elaborate more maybe as an answer with simplified code? The link you sent is somehow different from what I want to do.

Comment: Could you post a sample of the JSON you get from the first Ajax call please. I am working on an explainer but I am curious about that first response. You use a for-loop on result.length, but that would imply result is an array or string. I would expect to see result.innerObj.length.

Comment: I edited the original post and added a sample result set from first ajax call. after that (as shown in my code) I use : var result = JSON.parse(data);

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't think this is a very good approach to do. Can you make a `JOIN` in your **SQL** query to combine the outer and inner **AJAX** for avoiding 2 times **AJAX** request?

If not, try to make another function which contains your inner **AJAX** request and call it in your loop.

Comment: The OP is not asking for a redesign, and he may not be able to demand a change at the server, and irrespective of all that he poses a practical issue  of how to nest ajax functions correctly. It's a valid question as it stands.